# vim ignores keymapping, provided in .vimrc

Tags: vim

I have a .vimrc file (hosted in a git-repo), containing the following keymappings:

```
map <c-j> <c-w>j
map <c-k> <c-w>k
map <c-l> <c-w>l
map <c-h> <c-w>h
```

But recently, the mapping `<c-j>` stopped working, causing `<c-j>` to change to **insert-mode**.

My git-repository does not show any changes, but the `:map` command returns:

```
o  <NL>          <C-W>j
   <C-K>         <C-W>k
   <C-L>         <C-W>l
   <C-H>         <C-W>h
```

What could be the reason? And what does the `<NL>` stand for?

- Executing `:map <c-j> <c-w>j` after vim started, fixes the mapping.
- Doing a `noremap <c-j> <c-w>j` does not fix the problem
- Moving the mapping to the end of the vimrc-file also causes no success...

---

EDIT 1.0:

`:verbose map <c-j>` returns:

```
v  <NL>          <Plug>IMAP_JumpForward
    Last set from ~/.vim/bundle/vim-latex-suite/plugin/imaps.vim
n  <NL>          <Plug>IMAP_JumpForward
    Last set from ~/.vim/bundle/vim-latex-suite/plugin/imaps.vim
o  <NL>          <C-W>j
    Last set from ~/.vimrc
```

EDIT 2.0:

Disabling vim-latex-suite makes the mapping work again. But how can I combine both? Plugin+mapping?

Comment: What does :verbose map <c-j> give you?

Comment: See question (here, I cannot format properly)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *vim-latex-suite* plugin overrides your `<C-J>` mapping. (I don't know why it defines a global mapping; a buffer-local one for Latex files might suffice, but I don't know the plugin.) As the plugin supplies `<Plug>` mappings, it's easy to redefine the conflicting one in your `~/.vimrc`, e.g.:

```
nmap <Leader>j <Plug>IMAP_JumpForward
```

---

Under `:help key-notation`, you'll see that `<C-J>` and `<NL>` are equivalent. May Control key codes have special meaning:

> ```
> <NL>      linefeed        CTRL-J   10 (used for <Nul>)
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem on ***vim on Solaris 11***. The command `:map`  written in `./vim80/vimrc` has been ignored. This is the code:

```
map <Space>w :w!<CR>
map <Space>q :q!<CR>
map <Space>k Y
map <Space>v p
```

I use this to avoid typing too much:
<kbd>Space</kbd> <kbd>w</kbd> does the same as <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>:</kbd> <kbd>w</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>!</kbd>  <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

**The solution was** to write the code `not in vimrc but in defaults.vim`

I had this problem only on Solaris 11 on a virtual machine. Other unix distributions like RedHat or Debian and also vim on Windows worked as expected, namely with the :map-code in vimrc.